# Matching several ArrayList to find those similar lists

Tags: java, arraylist, match

I have three lists:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

list1.add("return");
list1.add("==");
list1.add("NULL");
list1.add("&&");
list1.add("password");

list2.add("password");
list2.add("&&");
list2.add("return");
list2.add("==");
list2.add("NULL");

list3.add("return");
list3.add("==");
list3.add("NULL");
```

I want to compare list1 with list2 and list3, if the similarity >= 0.6, it means that they are the similar list. In this example, both list2 and list3 are similar lists.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: (1) How do you define similarity? (2) Where is your best attempt, and in what way does it fail?

Comment: how to find the similar list, if list4 has list4.add("str.length"); list4.add("<"); list4.add("1000"); then list4 will not be the similar list as list1, but list2 and list3 are the similar lists. similarity = (# of the same elements) / (list1.size())

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Even better, edit your question and add the information in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 Stream to do that:
Using filter you can get all elements that occur in the first list and the second or in the first and the third. Then, using count you can check their amount.

```
long same12 = list1.stream()
                   .filter(s -> list2.contains(s))
                   .count();
long same13 = list3.stream()
                   .filter(s -> list1.contains(s))
                   .count();

System.out.println(((double)same12/(double)list1.size()) >= 0.6 ? "They are similar" : "They aren't similar");
System.out.println(((double)same13/(double)list1.size()) >= 0.6 ? "They are similar" : "They aren't similar");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a very good reason to use streams here (except that some of us love streams) when we have the good old Java collection set operations. This method should give you what you ask for:

```
public static boolean areSimilar(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    List<String> sameElements = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    sameElements.retainAll(list2);
    double similarity = ((double) sameElements.size()) / list1.size();
    return similarity > 0.5999999;
}
```

I have set the threashold slightly lower than your 0.6 to make quite sure that roundoff errors will not cause a similarity of 3 / 5 to be missed.

According to this method, any two of your three lists are similar. In these cases also both `areSimilar(list1, list2)` and `areSimilar(list2, list1)` yield `true`.

Say I introduce

```
    List<String> list4 = Arrays.asList("return", "password");
```

Now `areSimilar(list1, list4)` is `false`, but `areSimilar(list4, list1)` is true. In some cases the order of the arguments matters since you use the size of the first list in your similarity measure and the lists are not the same size. However, both `areSimilar(list3, list4)` and `areSimilar(list4, list3)` yield `false` since these two lists have only 1 element in common.